# Adressing external Wordpress Installation from primary Domain

Tags: redirects, wordpress, dns, google-ads, cname

I have a primary domain, let's call it company.com for example's sake. Under this domain there's a wordpress installation running where i am currently working on my "main Site".

I also currently have an AdWords campaign being run by an agency under a different domain, let's call it company-landingpage.com.

The Agency also uses a WordPress intallation on their part, with a custom developed template which is different from the template etc. on the main site. I would ideally like to also use the company.com domain for AdWords in such a way that for example a redirect from company.com/ads would show the contents from company-landingpage.com.

Doing a simple 301 redirect or such would most likely not be in accordance with the Adwords terms and conditons.

Is there any other way to accomplish this? The behaviour i basically want is that a user which enters company.com is landing on the "main site" i.e. wordpress installation 1. 
Users which enter company.com/ads would be shown the contents from the agency landinpages i.e. wordpress installation 2 which doesn't reside on the main site's server but on the agency's server?

Like i said it shouldn't be a simple redirect but it should rather behave as if it was possible to do a CNAME from company.com/ads to company-landingpage.com meaning that the URL in the users adress bar should still read company.com/ads.

Using subdomains would be the obvious choice but not the most aesthetically pleasing. Is there any clean way to do this? I'd be super thankful for any input and will provide clarifications in case my description was confusing.

Comment: That's a lot of text to be in one paragraph. Can you rewrite this so it this question is clearer and easier to understand?

Comment: You could use an iframe.

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht Thanks for your input. I was considering this option, but that's not the best solution in this case either, since AdWords will basically consider the landingpage empty, then. This in turn will result in a horrible Quality Score.

Comment: That's true, if the ad campaign is using the company.com/ads URL in the ads, if you were using the company-landingpage.com domain for the ad campaign, it wouldn't be an issue. I assume the problem you're trying to solve is that you want the externally hosted content to appear on company.com/ads as if it were hosted there? Could you not just get your ad agency to send you the WP database and set it up on your own domain?

Comment: Duplicate? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16119/wordpress-as-xml-rpc-client